# How to toggle slidBar menu programatically in swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift

Any one please tell me how to toggle (in-out) slidBar Menu programatically in SWRevealViewController in swift 2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show your tried code

Answer (score 1):

`SWRevealViewControllerSegue` is now deprecated and you should use `SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController` and `SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController` instead.
Use this link http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/

Comment: thanks for reply ...but it will work properly by using ctrl+drag to connect more view controllers,but i am doing it programatically,slid menu is opening but not hiding on select row from slid menu.